# Using LocationManager in an IntentService doesn't seem to work

Tags: android

I'm having an problem using LocationManager in my IntentService.  I'm developing an application to display a Map Image.  I want an IntentService to run the background to detect location changes.  When location updates are detected, the service will write the new location to the SQLite database.  The IntentService will send a Broadcast to the main Activity to let it know a new location has been stored.  The main app extracts the location for the database and moves the icon to the new location on the map.

Here is the code for the Service:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.widget.Toast;

import android.location.GpsStatus;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.GpsStatus.NmeaListener;

import android.location.LocationManager;

import android.database.*;

import android.util.Log;

// local imports
import com.saic.MCAppActivity;
import com.saic.db.*;

public class SaService extends IntentService {

    private static final String tag = "SaService";


    private Location loc = null;
    private Intent updateMapIntent = null;
    private LocationManager locMgr = null; 
    private boolean gps_provider = false;
    private boolean net_provider = false;

    public SaService ()
    {
       super( tag );
    }

    public SaService(String name)
    {
       super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
       updateMapIntent = new Intent();
       updateMapIntent.setAction( "UPDATE_LOCATION" );

       locMgr = MCAppActivity.getLocationManager();

       locMgr.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60, 0,
                                      locationListener );
       locMgr.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60, 0,
                                      locationListener );

       // loop until told to quit
       while ( !MCAppActivity.toQuit() )
       {
          try {
             Thread.sleep( 30000 );
          }
          catch ( InterruptedException e ) {}
          getBaseContext().sendBroadcast( updateMapIntent );
       }
       stopSelf();
    }


    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            double lat = 0.0;
            double lon = 0.0;

            // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
            if ( location.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) )
            {
               lat = location.getLatitude();
               lon = location.getLongitude();
               Log.i(tag, "LocationListener(): gps_provider location update:\nlat: " + lat +
                                               "\nlon: " + lon );
               writeLocationToDB( location );
            }
            else if ( location.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) )
            {
               lat = location.getLatitude();
               lon = location.getLongitude();
               Log.i(tag, "LocationListener(): net_provider location update:\nlat: " + lat +
                       "\nlon: " + lon );
               writeLocationToDB( location );
            }
            else
            {
               Log.i(tag, "LocationListener(): unknown provider found" );
            }
        }

        // don't need them now. make them NO-OP
        public void onStatusChanged ( String provider, int status, Bundle extras ) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled ( String provider )
        {
           Log.i( tag, "enable gps: "+ provider );
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled ( String provider )
        {
           Log.w( tag, "disable gps: "+ provider );
        }

    };

}
```

The LocationManager is defined in my MCAppActivity and passed to the Service.  I get no errors when running the application on my phone.  However, the listener is never invoked. Is there a problem with invoking the LocationManager in a Service as opposed to an Activity? I do know I have to change the minTime to something larger to avoid battery drain. For now, I just want to see if I can get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't use an `IntentService`, as you are fighting it -- `Thread.sleep()` in production code is a serious code smell. Take a look at my `LocationPoller` for another model: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll

Comment: So is IntentService suppressing the functionality of LocationManager?  I didn't read anything about this being a problem. (It may, but it seems weird the javadoc pages don't mention it.)

Comment: It's more that I think you're blocking the thread that `onLocationUpdate()` is supposed to be called upon.

Comment: So, is is the While() loop in the onHandleIntent() that is preventing any location updates to be realized?  I would have thought the Listener is callback invoked asynchronously.  I'm not sure how the while() loop is preventing the listener invocation.  I would have though once the listener was registered, I wouldn't to call requestLocationUpdates() (or maybe I DO have to?).

Comment: `onLocationChanged()`, by default, is called on the same thread that you called `requestLocationUpdates()`, assuming that thread has a `Looper` (e.g., it's a `HandlerThread`). "I would have though once the listener was registered, I wouldn't to call requestLocationUpdates()" -- `requestLocationUpdates()` *is* where you are registering the listener.

Comment: What I meant was, I should only have to call requestLocationUpdates() once to register the listeners.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for restarting the thread.

Why not just use a plain Service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

  private static final String TAG = "MyService";
  private LocationManager lm; // somewhere initialized
  private LocationListener ll; // somewhere initialized


  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,   ll,Looper.getMainLooper());
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    lm.removeUpdates(ll);
    super.onDestroy();
  }
}
```